# Rewriting to hide the querystring

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've been trying to create a page that can be accessed by passing a query string to check what version should be loaded. Instead of accessing the page by using `www.domain.com?version=one` I'd like to be able to use `www.domain.com/one` and the rule should turn `/one` into `/version=one`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /?version=$1 [L,QSA]
```